# What if URI path does not meet regex in Jax-RS

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

I have a JAX-RS resource, where I use GET on a user on a specific ID, I have used a regex pattern to match, that the URI only accepts digits. But would happened, if something else was entered, would it just throw an exception, because, if the method, did not found anything anyway wouldn't it be the same?

```
 @GET
@Path("/{id: [0-9]+}") // pattern to only match numbers between 0-9, but what would happen without it?
public Response getUser(@PathParam("id") int id) throws UserNotFoundException
{
    User   user    = userFacade.get(id);
    String jsonDTO = gson.toJson(UserDTO.basic(user));
    return Response.ok(jsonDTO).build();
}
```

Comment: Just try it and find out. You'll see that you will get a 404.

Comment: But then What is The purpose of The error occurs with and with The regex pattern?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question.

Comment: would it not give the same error, despite the regex string being there or not?

Comment: So you don't have to waste your time trying to process parameters that don't fit your criteria.